# Does Intelligent Design Sort really require no additional memory?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

So let's say I implement [Intelligent Design Sort](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/intelligentdesignsort.html) in a language (I'm using C#/Java for example):

```
public void Sort<T> ( T[] arr ) 
{
   return; 
}
```

The analysis says

> This algorithm is constant in time, and sorts the list in-place,
>   requiring no additional memory at all.

However, I'm wondering how this can be correct. Even though `T[] arr` is going to be a reference to an array in most languages, doesn't that parameter become a **copy** of a reference to a container, thus it is not "no memory." And doesn't the `return` statement end up as some sort of memory in machine language when it tells the operating system where to jump to? I am challenging specifically the idea that the algorithm uses no additional memory.

Comment: This is a joke algorithm. It's not real.

Comment: Though, as a general rule - "Requires no additional memory" usually means "Requires only a small, constant amount of additional memory." So it will use some, but that amount doesn't scale with the size of the task, and will thus generally be trivial.

Comment: The joke is essentially a claim that Intelligent Design is absurd, but it's not a very strong claim, because it swaps between two different notions of "order" (the "ordinary mortal" ascending kind, and the "unknowable" kind purported to have been furnished for us already by the Great Sorter) while pretending not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the concept of omnipotence, we don't actually need to pass the array. There is no need to make a copy of the reference as the sorting algorithm will already know where it is.

```
public void Sort<T> ()
{
    return;
}
```

Additionally, it is arguable that one does not need to implement the function at all. We can assume that the Creator has already seen to it that the function has already been implemented and called Elsewhere if it needs to be, so the sorting algorithm can be further reduced like so:

```
{ }
```

This is clearly of constant time and should adequately suffice to save every bit of runtime memory while still making use of one of the most advanced sorting algorithms we've ever come up with.